# Declare protocol in interface or class extension

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Is it better practice to declare a protocol in the interface or in a class extension:

**@interface**

MyViewController.h

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
@property NSString *myName;
@end
```

**vs**

MyViewController.m

```
#include "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
@end

@implementation MyViewController

@end
```

Comment: Is it, or does it need to be, public knowledge that the class conforms to these protocols? Does it matter to any other object besides the table view?

Comment: The practice I use is the same for anything else in the public interface:  Only if the caller needs to know.

Comment: The following assumes that `MyViewController` contains a table view that it manages...   I would be concerned if I saw someone using `MyViewController` as a table view Delegate/DataSource for a *different* table. So I'm going to go one step further and say that it should **not** be "public". Exposing it would allow someone else to use this view controller in a way that was not intended.